# How to iterate list with references to class instance values?

Tags: python, list, max

I am making an adventure game in python, and I have a sword class - and I have a function, whose purpose is to find the most powerful sword in the list (I will be modifying this function later on to be a player inventory, but irrelevant). I keep getting the error that the "int type is non-iteratable", which is odd to me, because it seems that it works for others when it is just a number, and not a reference to a value in the instance of a class. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

```
class Sword:
    def __init__(self, name=None, strength=None, description=None):
        self.name = name
        self.strength = strength
        self.description = description


rusty_sword = Sword(
    name="rusty sword",
    strength=5,
    description="This is a rusty old sword that you found on the ground.",
)
gold_sword = Sword(
    name="gold sword",
    strength=15,
    description="This is a fine golden sword, with a crown engraved on the handle.",
)
diamond_sword = Sword(
    name="diamond sword",
    strength=45,
    description="This 100% pure diamond sword is of the finest quality. It reflects a prism of light when you turn it back and forth.",
)
plasma_sword = Sword(
    name="plasma sword",
    strength=135,
    description="This plasma sword can slay any opponent. With this, you are unstoppable.",
)


def mostpowerfulsword():
all_swords = (rusty_sword, gold_sword, diamond_sword, plasma_sword)
for sword in all_swords:
    swordstrength = sword.strength
    print(max(swordstrength))
```

Comment: Just a style note, the `mostpowerfulsword` function should absolutely be named according to python's style conventions ie `get_most_powerful_sword` and it should accept a list of swords as a parameter, rather than having the list (technically you hard-coded a tuple) hard-coded in there.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling the `max` function on `swordstrength` which is an `int`. You overwrite `swordstrength` value on every iteration of your loop. I suspect you want to build a list and pass that to the `max` function.

So you should change your `mostpowerfulsword` function to look something like this:

```
def mostpowerfulsword():
    all_swords = (rusty_sword, gold_sword, diamond_sword, plasma_sword)
    swordstrengths = []
    for sword in all_swords:
        swordstrengths.append(sword.strength)
    print(max(swordstrengths))
```

Comment: Or `max([ sword.strength for sword in all_swords])`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon no need to actually make a list. Use a generator expression :) `max(sword.strength for sword in all_swords)`

Comment: @ReutSharabani Nice! even better.

Comment: @ReutSharabani your version will give the biggest value of the attribute `strength` not the actual `Sword` object, i.e. your version will output `135` with the examples provided above. Not really useful if you want to find the sword associated to it...

Comment: so, your `mostpowerfulsword` is `135`. Seems more like a number than a `Sword` object, no?!

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you to overwrite comparison behavior in the class:

```
class Sword:
    def __init__(self, name=None, strength=None, description=None):
        self.name = name
        self.strength = strength
        self.description = description

    def __lt__(self, other):
      return self.strength < other.strength

    def __gt__(self, other):
      return self.strength > other.strength

    def __eq__(self, value):
      return self.strength == other.strength


rusty_sword = Sword(
    name="rusty sword",
    strength=5,
    description="This is a rusty old sword that you found on the ground.",
)
gold_sword = Sword(
    name="gold sword",
    strength=15,
    description="This is a fine golden sword, with a crown engraved on the handle.",
)
diamond_sword = Sword(
    name="diamond sword",
    strength=45,
    description="This 100% pure diamond sword is of the finest quality. It reflects a prism of light when you turn it back and forth.",
)
plasma_sword = Sword(
    name="plasma sword",
    strength=135,
    description="This plasma sword can slay any opponent. With this, you are unstoppable.",
)
```

This allows you to use python `>`, `<`, `==` operators (you can overwrite more) but with these 3 the whole code to find which is the stronger would be:

```
swords = [rusty_sword, gold_sword, diamond_sword, plasma_sword]
print(f"The strongest sword of them all is: {max(swords).name}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a `key` attribute to `max` and indicate with a `lambda`-expression what attribute it is you want to find the maximum of:

```py
max(all_swords, key=lambda x: x.strength).name
```

will give:

```
Out[15]: 'plasma sword'
```

Then your function might look like:

```py
def get_most_powerful_sword(*swords):
    return max(swords, key=lambda x: x.strength)
```

and you'd call it like:

```
get_most_powerful_sword(rusty_sword, gold_sword, diamond_sword, plasma_sword)
```

*Note: If `strength` is the only attribute you might use to compare objects from your `Sword` class I would recommend using the [answer by Nf4r](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931309/1622937)*